# How to include external webapp files during gradle build

Tags: java, eclipse, web, gradle

Am trying to combine the "src/main/webapp" contents from multiple projects during the build process.  Would have thought this could be achieved using sourceSets rule

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            srcDir project(':core').file('src/main/java')           
            srcDir project(':mongodb').file('src/main/java')           
            srcDir project(':tripper').file('src/main/java')           
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources'
            srcDir project(':core').file('src/main/resources')           
            srcDir project(':mongodb').file('src/main/resources')           
            srcDir project(':tripper').file('src/main/resources')           
        }
        webapp {
            srcDir 'src/main/webapp'
            srcDir project(':core').file('src/main/webapp')           
        }
    }
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/test/resources'
            srcDir project(':core').file('src/test/resources')           
        }
    }
}
```

When I run *gradle clean build* I get the following error.

```
$ gradle clean build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\mikem\git\workbench\payment\build.gradle' line: 45

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':payment'.
> Could not find method webapp() for arguments [build_anxrainh90symveso782viscs$_run_closure2$_closure6$_closure10@38dc5714] on source set 'main' of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSet.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

I seems that there is no build location for *webapp*, so can't run a folder copy task during the build process either.

Documentation describes
    war {
       includes '...'
       from '...'
    }
but not seeing the content included in the war and no error shown.

Anyone know if this is possible or a different technique that would do this task?

:(

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: There are core typescripts and static pages that I want shared between multiple web applications.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a separate task for war and make war depend on it.

```
task copyOther(type: Copy){
  from //location
  into "$webAppDirName" //src/main/webapp

 }

war.dependsOn copyOther
```

As you are not creating any folder that is not known to `clean` task it should be able to clean the files